# data members as pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

let's say I have the next class which include many data memebers:

```
Class A
{
public:
  .
  .
  .

private:

  string a1;
  string a2;
  vector<string> vec1;
  .
  .
  .
  .

}
```

and let's say I have a recursive function called foo() with many local variables of type A:

```
void foo()
{
  A a_1;
  A a_2;
  A a_3;
  .
  .
  .
  A a_n;
}
```

as you can see in the class definition, today, the data members of A are real objects and not pointers.
I know that all those data members are stored on the stack, the stack has a limited size (in my case 512MB) and I was wandering, will it be better to replace the data members with pointers which will point to data on the heap?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you use the pointers for. You need to be more specific.

Comment: It's not much different from deciding when to implement ordinary variables as pointers or real variables.

Comment: Don't forget that in C++ you have references too. And *if* you need to use pointers, think about using [smart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) [pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: The simple rule is "don't use pointers". The advanced rule is "don't use pointers unless you know what you're doing with them".

Comment: You'd be surprised how much you can achieve with `int`, `string`, `vector<>`, and `struct` to combine them together.  Pass these around by value most of the time. And take a parameter by reference, on occasion, when you want to use that variable as an output-parameter.

Comment: One consideration I make is to see if the variable should assume a value from the moment object is created (till it is destroyed). If so, I would go with variable. But if the variable is assigned a value conditionally or can be deferred, you can look at pointers. Deferring the variable initialization when you can would reduce the cost of object creation.
And for primitive types, I would go with variables than pointers unless there is really good reason. 
That said it's always a case-by-case call

Comment: "Always favour the stack".  Or to put it another way, always put things on the stack unless you absolutely can't do so.

Comment: @user1158692 but the stack has limited size and in my case the class I want to instantiate has many data members.

Comment: @eladm26 What target are you developing for?  Unless it's a mobile or emebedded target with documented directions on avoiding the stack you can, basically, usually, all usual caveats apply, treat the stack as unlimited.

Comment: @user1158692: No you can't. On most popular platforms, the stack is limited to a few megabytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the rule of thumb is "don't complicate your life by using pointers *if you don't need to*".

In C++, there are **references**, that are (in my humble opinion) easier to use and understand. Regarding methods in a class, it's often necessary to pass objects by reference so that you avoid destroying objects you will need; but as far as variables go, I don't think it's very common that you need to use pointers. :)

Comment: Hi Eutherpy and thanks for the answer, in my case I can't use references because I want to be able to change the value of my class' data members.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible answer, if you know the exact type of the object at runtime, use the stack variables or references. If you do not know the type of an object at runtime, use the pointers. The same rule applies to the arguments of functions. Thank you.

Comment: When you say runtime, do you mean compile-time?

Comment: No, under runtime, I mean an execution stage of the final application/executable.